# How can I restart record ids at 1 Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake-task

I have a rake task to populate a table.

as follows:

```
namespace :db do
  desc  "fill in the database with icons data"
  task :populate_icons => :environment do 
    make_types
    make_templates
    make_categories
    make_greeting_icons
    make_user_icons
  end
end

  def make_types
    Type.delete_all
    types = %w{Classic Popular Children Animals}
    types.each do |type|   
      Type.create!(:name => type, :adult => false) #1
    end
  end
```

I can't drop the database as some tables will have user data in them.

I need to restart the id's at 1 when I re-seed the tables.

How can I do this in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSql, to restart your sequence:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE table_id_seq RESTART 1;
```

You can also do that through the model connection:

```
MyModel.connection.execute('ALTER SEQUENCE my_models_id_seq RESTART 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

For mysql try this snippet

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=1')
```